# Plugin another project in current window

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, reflection

I'm creating a WPF application with a menu, when clicked on menuItem I want to show NQueens (another project) in my Window (plugin). I've placed an NQueens.dll in my CurrentDirectory to work with. To make this work I've created an assembly object to load the classes and created an instance of Nqueens.Nqueen and invoked the methods.

The NQueens project consists of a class NQueen.cs and a MainWindow.

```
namespace NQueens
{
public class NQueen
{
   public static bool berekenQueens(int Row, int N, bool[,] bord)
   {
       if (Row >= N) return true;  //stopconditie

       for (int Col = 0; Col < N; Col++)
       {
           //Q toevoegen
           bord[Row, Col] = true;

           //Q + Q volgende Row  controleren
           if (bordValidatie(Row, Col, bord, N) && berekenQueens(Row + 1, N, bord))
           {
               return true;
           }

           //Q verwijderen indien niet door controle
           bord[Row, Col] = false;

       }
       return false;
   }

   private static bool bordValidatie(int currentRow, int currentCol, bool[,] currentBord, int N)
   {
       int colstep = 1;
       for (int i = currentRow - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
           //rechte lijn 
           if (currentBord[i, currentCol])
               return false;

           //linker diagonaal
           if (currentCol - colstep >= 0)
           {
               if (currentBord[i, currentCol - colstep])
                   return false;
           }
           //rechter diagonaal
           if (currentCol + colstep < N)
           {
               if (currentBord[i, currentCol + colstep])
                   return false;
           }
           colstep += 1;
       }
       return true;
   }
}
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace NQueens
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public int iN { get { return Convert.ToInt32(txtN.Text); } set { txtN.Text = "" + value; } }
    private bool[,] spelbord;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        spelbord = new bool[iN, iN];
        NQueen.berekenQueens(0, iN, spelbord);

        visualise(iN, spelbord);
    }

    private void visualise(int N, bool[,] bord)
    {
        gridTekenen();

        for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

                TextBlock txtB = new TextBlock();

                if (spelbord[row, col])
                {
                    SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                    mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.LightGreen;
                    rect.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;

                    txtB.Text = "Q";
                }

                rect.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, col);
                rect.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);

                txtB.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, col);
                txtB.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);

                gridPaneel.Children.Add(rect);
                gridPaneel.Children.Add(txtB);
            }
        }
    }

    private void gridTekenen()
    {
        gridPaneel.ShowGridLines = true;
        int grooteGrid = int.Parse(txtN.Text);

        RowDefinition rowDef;
        ColumnDefinition colDef;


        for (int i = 0; i < grooteGrid; i++)
        {
            rowDef = new RowDefinition();

            GridLengthConverter myGridLengthConverter = new GridLengthConverter();
            GridLength gl1 = (GridLength)myGridLengthConverter.ConvertFromString(150 + "*");
            rowDef.Height = gl1;

            colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
            colDef.Width = gl1;

            gridPaneel.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
            gridPaneel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Code in WPF application when clicked on the menuItem.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an assembly object to load our classes
        string path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\NQueens.dll";
        Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
        Console.WriteLine(path);

        Type objType = ass.GetType("NQueens.NQueen");

        // Create an instace of NQueens.NQueen
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);

        // public static bool berekenQueens(int Row, int N, bool[,] bord)
        var result = objType.InvokeMember("berekenQueens",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
        null, instance, new object[] {   1, /* Row */ 1, /* N */ new bool[,] { {true,false} } /* bord */
        });

        // private static bool bordValidatie(int currentRow, int currentCol, bool[,] currentBord, int N)
        var result2 = objType.InvokeMember("bordValidatie", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null, instance, new object[] {   1, /* Row */ 1, /* N */ new bool[,] { {true,false} } /* bord */, 1
        });
    }
```

I do not know what to do now. How can I show the NQueen program in my current Window when clicked on the menuItem.

Comment: BTW, it would help if your code and comments were in English, most people here don't speak Dutch.

Comment: The NQueens project works, so it doesn't matter that some comments or methods are in dutch. The only problem is implementing the NQueens project in antoher project.

Answer (score 0):

NQueen class should be any kind of wpf control descendant. If it's a simple class, it cannot communicate with its container.

Answer (score 0):

So you should instanciate *NQueens.MainWindow* instead of *NQueens.NQueen* and call the *Show* method.